# toggle parent div on child div hover

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am new to vuejs, I want to change the whole background (parent div class = "home") from white to an image by hovering an image from child div (id ="ds"). My code works but the changes happens only on the child div. I am new to vuejs. Can you please help me

here is my script

```
 methods: {
getData() {
  var ds = document.querySelector('#ds');
    ds.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
        this.classList.remove('home');
        this.classList.add('dshov');
})
    ds.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
        this.classList.add('home');
        this.classList.remove('dshov');
  })
  },
},
```

and here is the css

```
.home{
  background: white;
.dshov{
  background: url('../assets/images/bg.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
```

}

Comment: `this.parentElement.classList...`.

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Please tell me more [about it](https://jsfiddle.net/xqek9tbf/1/).

Comment: the template goes parent div then inside it is a div and div2 inside it and div3 again and inside it is the child div that i am hovering,

Comment: when i hover the child div, the background only changes within that child div, how can i toggle the child div and the whole background changes?

Comment: And you didn't find that being important information to add to you question? Instead you explicitly said "_parent div class = "home"_). Pleas ask what you need, don't just write something ... Give a persistent class name to the wrapper element and use `this.closest('.persistent-class-name').classList ...`.

Comment: it is working now, thank you so much! I appreciate it and will take note of your comments :)